# PushAsync runs without await

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I'm using `Navigation.PushAsync` to navigate to a new page and when the work is done, it will call `PopAsync` to return to previous page. The problem is the first page needs to wait to the new page to pop and then continue some work. So I'm doing like this:

```
// source page:
DoWork();
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TargetPage());  <== this does not wait for the page!??
DoOtherWork();
```

I observed that the `DoOtherWork` part runs immediately when the new page is shown, not until it is dismissed. But I'm using `await` here, so that means the later part should be a continuation upon the async task is finished, right? Why is it run without waiting for the Navigation task?

Comment: Is the Task finished when the new page is shown or when it is dismissed? You are assuming the latter. But is your assumption correct? From what you describe, I'd expect the former to be the case.

Comment: You mean the task only manages the display of the page, not waiting its dismissal? Then how can the navigation connects the two pages?

Comment: See the example here : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/ It seems that you need to await Pop to wait for dismissal. The documentation text for Return is a little confusing to me. It seems to contradict the example? Maybe that's just me, though.

Comment: It looks confusing to me too, because the examples is shows the opposite meaning of the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TargetPage());
```

This code "await" until the "TargetPage" is visualized, then code continue with "OnOtherCode".

If you want to execute some code after TargetPage is closed, you should add this code after `Navigation.PopAsync`, or in "TargetPage's OnDisappearing" event.

Another solution can be: use a `MessagingCenter.Send` in "TargetPage's OnDisappearing" event and subscribe to the same message in the Calling Page

Comment: Ok, I see. But DoOtherWork will need to access data in the source page, that's why I'm doing it after the push, not after pop in the target page.

Comment: Source page is "TargetPage" or the "CallerPage"?

Comment: Source is the first page calling `PushAsync`, target is the second page calling `PopAsync` to dismiss itself.

Comment: Do you need DoOtherWork starts after TargetPage is dismissed?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I want to do

Comment: As I suggested, you can send a message from Target to Caller. When Caller receive the message, execute your DoOtherWork.

Comment: Ok, I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way:

```
public async Task<bool> openContentPageForResult()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> waitToCloseTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    MyPage myNewPage = new MyPage();
    myNewPage.Disappearing += (sender2, e2) =>
    {
        waitToCloseTask.SetResult(true);
    };
    await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(myNewPage);
    return await waitToCloseTask.Task;
}
```

Then just call this method and await for the result, in this case a boolean result.

```
bool myResult = await openContentPageForResult();
```